# How long is the Temple of Elemental Evil (T1-4) campaign?

Tags: published-adventures, adnd-1e

I was thinking about playing some old-school D&D campaign with friends, and Temple of the Elemental Evil came to mind as it is an iconic and well-received module. However, I heard that it is pretty massive. What ballpark of size are we talking about here to complete the whole scenario? 10, 20, 50 sessions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its pretty massive - how many sessions depends on how long your sessions are, how efficient your party is at dealing with encounters and how you strike the balance between role-play, exploration and combat.

The Temple itself has 435 keyed locations with four attached "elemental nodes" of about 25-35 keyed locations. In addition, the moathouse contains 32 keyed locations, there are two villages, Hommlet and Nulb with 31 and 3 keyed locations each.

The back of the module says "... this product provides a complete campaign adventure which will take beginning characters from 1st all the way to 8th level and possibly beyond!" From memory, when I played I think we reached 10-12th level and spent several years of real time doing so. That said, we treated it as a combat grind - there are ways to by-pass whole chunks of the temple by using diplomacy and playing one temple faction off against the others.

Comment: How frequently did you have sessions during those years? (There's a big difference between "50 sessions a year" and "3 each year, as long as everyone was available.")

Comment: Several years, wow. I think I'd run the T1, gauge involvement and interest and then decide if we want to continue or jump to another adventure. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @GMJoe I was in high school and had no other social life so once a week or so. Now its more like 3 sessions per year.

Comment: It took us half a dozen sessions to get through T1 and then our group broke up due to people going to sea.  I wish I could answer this question but we never finished it.

Comment: Playing 4h per week almost every weeks, it took us 2 years with a party of 6 to 8 players.

Comment: Good review.  It might be worth noting that the module has explicit rules for replacing losses on the side of the monsters.  Thus, if the players are not strategic in eliminating the factions and efficient in their use of time and resources, they may not run out of opponents for quite some time or return to the Temple and find it even better defended than on their last foray.  This has the potential to interact strongly with 1e rules about training time after leveling.

Answer (score 0):

Just crunching some estimated numbers in support of Dale M's answer:

Dale points out that the moathouse & temple together have 32 + 435 = 467 keyed areas (not counting the elemental nodes). Traditionally tournament games at the time assumed a 4-hour time slot, and up to 9 areas of content cleared in that time (e.g., see the AD&D A-series tournament play specifications). Based on that, we might estimate:

467 / 9 = 52 sessions (4 hours each).

Alternatively, given that the adventure advertises itself as covering levels 1 through 8, we might look at Gygax's estimate for level advancement in D&D:

> It is reasonable to calculate that if a fair player takes part in 50
> to 75 games in the course of a year he should acquire sufficient
> experience points to make him about 9th to 11th level... [The
> Strategic Review, Vol. 2, #2, p. 23, 1976]

This works out to an average of about 6 game sessions per level. So the leveling velocity suggests it might take:

8 × 6 = 48 sessions (4 hours each)

Thus, it seems like a rough estimate of about 50 games sessions is in the ballpark. Again, this ignores the elemental node areas; which all told might add another dozen sessions or more.

(The advancement rate quote was fresh in my mind because I recently [blogged about that](http://deltasdnd.blogspot.com/2023/01/advancement-in-classic-d.html).)